# How is it possible to create an object from the abstract class?

Tags: c#, arrays, abstract-class

We know that the Array class in c# is abstract.

But the static CreateInstance method of this class returns an object of the Array class.

How is it possible?

Comment: A better question is "why do you believe it is impossible?"  Suppose Animal is an abstract class. Does that mean that you cannot have a method that returns an Animal? Can you explain why you think this is not possible?

Comment: Thank you Eric. I thought that CreateInstance method returns Array class object directly.

Answer (score 6):

#### Description

No, you cant create an instance of an abstract class.

> **MSDN**: Abstract classes are closely related to interfaces. **They are classes that cannot be instantiated**, and are frequently either partially implemented, or not at all implemented. One key difference between abstract classes and interfaces is that a class may implement an unlimited number of interfaces, but may inherit from only one abstract (or any other kind of) class. A class that is derived from an abstract class may still implement interfaces. Abstract classes are useful when creating components because they allow you specify an invariant level of functionality in some methods, but leave the implementation of other methods until a specific implementation of that class is needed. They also version well, because if additional functionality is needed in derived classes, it can be added to the base class without breaking code.

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Abstract Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k535acbf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

It's a static factory method that returns an instance of array. this example creates an array of length 10 for integer value types.

```
System.Array myIntArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int),10);
```

This should give you some more detail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb3cfh7k.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The various overloads of the method `Array.CreateInstance()` are typed as returning `Array`, which indeed is an abstract class. But the type of the object they return is not directly `Array`, it's some type that *inherits* from `Array` (what type exactly depends on the overload used and the parameters you pass in).

For example:

```
Array a = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 10); //create some array
Type type = a.GetType(); // type is int[], which is not abstract
Type baseType = type.BaseType; // baseType is Array
```

Basically, it's the same principle like the following factory method:

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public static Animal CreateInstance(AnimalType animalType)
    {
        if (animalType == AnimalType.Cat)
            return new Cat();
        if (animalType == AnimalType.Dog)
            return new Dog();
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Here, `Animal` is an abstract base type, `Cat` and `Dog` are concrete types that inherit from `Animal` and `animalType` tells us which type should the method return.

Now, arrays are treated specially in several ways in .Net (for example, there are IL instructions specifically for dealing with arrays). But they are not an exception in the type system (except, maybe for array covariance).

Answer (score 1):

`Array` seems to be a special case of abstract class. From what I've read in [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx)  I'd suggest that `Array` creation and functions are somehow handled internally in .NET Framework code - most probably extensively using native code for better performance results. I think that's why this class have been made abstract.

I'd be glad if someone more knowledgable of .NET Framework internals can improve my answer.

Comment: @HojjatEsmaeilzadeh: 
`Now, arrays are treated specially in several ways in .Net (for example, there are IL instructions specifically for dealing with arrays).`
That's actually what I wanted to say - just didn't know the details :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to relate to this situation is by considering a method that returns you instance of an interface!!!

Well, you know that we can *not* create instance of an interface, but internally a method may know about a class implementing that interface and return instance of that class.

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Circle : Shape
    {
        public override void Draw()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Draw a Circle");
        }
    }

    public abstract class Shape
    {    
        public abstract void Draw();
    }
}
```

You can do like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {       
        Shape v;
        v = new Circle();
        v.Draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.